# Dax query to get number of bussiness days (Excluding saturdays and sundays in a week)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

For example if we have slicer with the date range from 1/1/2022 to 31/01/2022 , need to get the result of 21(working days)

Comment: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/counting-working-days-in-dax/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Date table, you could use this DAX measure:

```
Working Days = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Date Table'), 
    FILTER('Date Table', 
        Not WEEKDAY('Date Table'[Date],2) in {6,7}
    )
)
```

The '2' in the WEEKDAY function indicates that the week should start with Monday as 1 and, therefore Saturday = 6 and Sunday = 7. We are then filtering the Date Table for any dates that are not Saturday or Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

```
count working days =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Dim table' ),
    FILTER (
        'Dim table',
        'Dim table'[Date].[Day] <= DAY ( TODAY () )
            && 'Dim table'[Date].[MonthNo] = MONTH ( TODAY () )
            && 'Dim table'[Weekday] <= 5
)
)
```

Recall that 'Dim table' is where the date column sits

All the best